# How to Use Bundle In SwiftUI with Image

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

For example:
i have Bundle in project   , it is call "Game.Bundle"

```
let b :Bundle = Bundle.init(path: Bundle.main.path(forResource:"Game", ofType:"bundle")!)!
Image("Giyuu",bundle:self.b)
```

but Bundle not work .

how can i use  custom  Bundle

[image]

Comment: The provided screen shot does not show "skill2" image in Game.bundle. Are you sure it is there?

Comment: yes i updated this question

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SwiftUI `Image(_ , bundle: _)` looks for image resource in corresponding bundle's Assets catalog. In your case the image is just embedded as regular file, so you have to find and load it as file. `Image` itself cannot do that, so it should be constructed with `UIImage` that has such possibility.

So, assuming you `Game.bundle` is in `PlugIns` subfolder of main bundle (if not - just correct corresponding path construction below) here is possible approach.

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: gameImage(name: "test") ?? UIImage())
    }

    func gameImage(name: String, type: String = "png") -> UIImage? {
        guard let plugins = Bundle.main.builtInPlugInsPath,
              let bundle = Bundle(url: URL(fileURLWithPath:
                           plugins).appendingPathComponent("Game.bundle")),
              let path = bundle.path(forResource: name, ofType: type)
              else { return nil }
        return UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to simple  and use image(String, bundle: Bundle?)

Comment: Then put your Giyuu.png into Assets catalog of Game.bundle.

Answer (score 2):

Your snippet as provided seems to reference `b` both in `self` as an instance and as a local variable

```
let b :Bundle = Bundle.init(path: Bundle.main.path(forResource:"Game", ofType:"bundle")!)!
Image("Giyuu",bundle:self.b)
```

Did you want?

```
let bundle :Bundle = Bundle.init(path: Bundle.main.path(forResource:"Game", ofType:"bundle")!)!
let image = Image("Giyuu",bundle:bundle)
```

Or refactored to eliminate force unwraps `!` with some problem analysis added.

```
func getGiyuuImage() -> Image {
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource:"Game", ofType:"bundle"), let bundle = Bundle(path: path) else {
        fatalError("dev error - no Game bundle")
    }
    let image = Image("Giyuu",bundle: bundle)
    return image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use my extension:

```
extension Image {
    init(path: String) {
        self.init(uiImage: UIImage(named: path)!)
    }
}
```

In SwiftUI:

```
Image(path: "Game.bundle/Giyuu.png")
```