# UIImage init directly from file

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiimage

I've simple question to you guys. Which init for UIImage should I use when I want to provide image directly from folder inside xcproject.
[image]

Let me make it clear a little more. I created directory in Xcode project called "data", then I've added there some svg files.

Now I want to put it inside UIImage, to be more specific Image(uiImage: UIImage). Now I don't know how to pass path and which init should I use for the UIImage.

[image]

Post Scriptum: I know that the easies way to add those images is to put them into assets folder, but for me it would be more convenient.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63472549/12299030?

Comment: "Folder inside the project" tells us nothing about what happens to this folder when your app is running. The folder may not even be deployed to the device, or if it is is, we don't know how you are deploying it. So in order to make your question answerable, please specify not how folder looks in project, but how does it look and can be accessed at runtime

Comment: To add to the very good comments, why **not** use assets? It's not just the easiest way, it's the *right* way. Most (but not all) devices aren't 1x anymore, but there's definitely 2x and 3x out there. And it's entirely possible to add images to your app package, but you haven't given us enough info to help you.